# React cloning fragments

Tags: reactjs

With React 16 we can now use fragments and return an array of elements/components without wrapping it with a div.
My question is, can we some how iterate through the returned array for purposes like cloning each elements in the array?

for example, lets say I have the following components:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Comp extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>Comp</div>
    }
}

class Comps extends Component {
    render() {
        return [
            <Comp key='2'/>,
            <Comp key='2'/>,
            <Comp key='2'/>,
            <Comp key='2'/>
        ];
    }
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
class Lol extends Component {
    render() {
        const lol = <Comps />;
        return lol.map(x => React.cloneElements(x, {
            className: 'lol'
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: First, as I underatand, Comps is a component, that means that you can only get its relevant inner key and this is what you want to map over, not iterate on Comps. Second, I think that is the wrong way. Why dont you add to Comps your desired props, such as className, then pass it to each Comp element in the array?

Comment: Its just a simple example, my problem is more complicated than that

Answer (score 1):

A React component is still a native js class so - yes, you can do this but the fact is - you should not.

It is a hacky way and it is an obvious anti-pattern which should be avoided:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return [
      <h1>Hello</h1>, 
      <h1>World</h1>
    ];
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const Headers = new Hello().render()

  return (
    <div>
    {
      Headers.map(Header => React.cloneElement(Header, { className: 'lol' }))
    }
    </div>
  )
};
```

live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/3yj69vqpz6

A better way is to move the list of components to a pure function which returns an array of components.

```
const Headers = () => (
  [
    <h1>Hello</h1>,
    <h1>World</h1>
  ]
)

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      { /* you can map it because it is an array */}    
      { Headers().map(Header => React.cloneElement(Header, {className: 'lol' })) }

      { /* you can use it as a component */}
      <Headers />
    </div>
  )
}
```

live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/jl0m70yq35

Comment: Yeah I know I cant simply map the component, was wondering if there is a build in feature, kind of like React.Children. But the second suggestion seems good